# Ответ из гугл таблицы через google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess) приходит с задержкой

Tags: html, google-apps-script

На html-форме сделана процедура ввода данных пользователем в инпуты и перехода курсора по нажатию кнопки Ентер. Поссле ввода данных в 3ий инпут и нажатия Ентер данные пишутся в гугл таблицу.

гугл таблица с проектом лежит здесь https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FqUmJcTipwKX9Q5m-4dlmXIChp5k1Z98xR2m42GpIT0/edit#gid=0

проект опубликован как веб-приложение здесь https://script.google.com/a/fmlogistic.com/macros/s/AKfycbwAcfIVGrbcu24t_6OxtR2gvltG3ojbh1_pNxLed1O8/dev

При вводе данных пользователем и нажатии ентер, данные проходят через функцию keyPressFunction(ev) и далее есть отправка запроса на сервер, т.е. в гугл таблицу через google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).searchData(inputData, curInpID), в гугл таблице в модуле Actions в функции searchData(inputData, curInpID) проходит проверка введенных данных со значениями таблиц на листе @sistem и потом назад данные возвращаются через onSuccess в переменную findData в формате "true/false".

Проблема в том, что курсор на следующий инпут может перейти раньше, чем придет ответ от сервера, что неправильно. Подскажите пожалуйста, можно ли сделать своего рода задержку для получения данных с сервера типа sleep либо рекурсию для перезапуска функции keyPressFunction(ev) до тех пор, пока с сервера не придет реальный ответ?

Если хотите, я могу приложить все скрипты здесь, написанные в проекте, но все это есть в самом проекте внутри, можете посмотреть по ссылкам выше.

Comment: Может кто нибудь помочь?

Comment: Коллега с иностранной версии stackoverflow посоветовал поставить перед  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).searchData(inputData, curInpID); вот это - inputs.removeEventListener('keydown', keyPressFunction), а внутри функции onSuccess добавить вот это - inputs.addEventListener('keydown', keyPressFunction); но суть это не поменяло, срабатывает точно также. Может что то можно поправить. Я не исключаю , что возможно скрипт нужно где то переписать. Прошу, помогите пожалуйста)

Comment: У меня вообще не переходит курсор никуда. Мне кажется, что вы слишком переусердствуете с поведением пользователя. Сейчас для вас должен быть важнее функционал, а не удобство приложения.

Comment: contributorpw нет, вам кажется) эта страничка будет открываться на терминале сбора данных или сканере. Пользователь сканирует штрихкода, при сканировании практически происходит ввод и нажатие кнопки Enter, поэтому важен переход курсора

Comment: contributorpw Если вы пытаетесь вводить данные сразу после загрузки страницы, попробуйте попробуйте ввести данные например 0001 в инпут Login и 3 раза нажать Enter.

Comment: Я бы сделал по другому. Например, определил бы автомат порядка работы с полями и реализовал бы его. Вызовы внутри функционала - опасный способ достижения цели.

Comment: contributorpw простите, но я не понимаю, о чем вы говорите. У меня мало опыта и знаний тоже((